# How to delete the node immediately preceding a node with a negative key a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

As title, I have a linked list implemented in C++. Now I would like to delete all the nodes preceding any node with negative key. I use 3 node pointers: 
`*prevNode`, `*currNode` and `*nextNode` to traverse the list. Any time I found the key in `*nextNode` is < 0, I delete the `*currNode` and continue until reaching the end of the list. When deleting a node, I also check whether it is the first node in the list or not.

Here is my C++ code:

```
void deletePrecedingNegative(LinkedList *l){
    Node *prevNode=NULL;
    Node *currNode=l->head;
    Node *nextNode=NULL;
    while(currNode->next){
        nextNode = currNode->next;
        if(nextNode->data < 0){
            if(currNode == l->head){
                l->head = nextNode;
                delete currNode;
                currNode = nextNode;
            }
            else{
                prevNode->next = nextNode;
                delete currNode;
                currNode = nextNode;
            }
        }
        else{
            prevNode = currNode;
            currNode = nextNode;
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone has better solution? Please let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks pretty optimal.

Comment: Your function name is delete`Preceding`Negative but you start `Node *currNode=l->head;`

Comment: @t.m. Thanks. But I'm looking forward a better idea
@macroland That's right. `currNode` is the first node to be deleted or not depending on the value of `nextNode`, aka  "preceding"

Comment: You can write `currNode = nextNode;` only once. That would be a slight improvement for readability and shorter code.

Comment: @A.S.H I actually think about it so thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

#### If it is deleting all the nodes preceeding the node holding negative key, It means deleting all the nodes preceeeding the last node holding negative key.

```
void DeleteNodesPreceedinglastNegative(LinkedList* l)
{
     Node *currNode=l->head;
     Node *tempNode=l->head;
     while(tempNode->Next)
     {
        tempNode = tempNode->Next;
        if(tempNode->Data < 0)
        {
             while(currNode != tempNode)
             {
                l->head = currNode->Next;
                delete currNode;
                currNode = l->head;
             }
        }
     }
     currNode = NULL;
     tempNode = NULL;
}
```

Comment: No the question is deleting then move on till the end of the list

Comment: are you saying the list should change from (1,0,-1,2,-5,7,8,-9) to (1,-1,-5,7,-9)

Comment: exactly what it is